# How to install picasa with wine

Tags: wine, picasa

Whenever I try to install picasa with wine it get this,

```
mr-yeomans@mryeomans-Dell-DE051:~$ wine ~/picasa39-setup.exe  
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000008 at address 0x7e5585e3 (thread 0029), starting debugger...
winedbg: Internal crash at 0x7e8685e3
mr-yeomans@mryeomans-Dell-DE051:~$
```

I don't know where to go on this.

Comment: Report a bug to wine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using playonlinux. You can get it from Ubuntu software center. Then, open it, click install, in search enter picasa, and select it, and then click install. Follow the very simple instructions and play on linux will do the rest(set wineprefix, download the right version of wine, and you can even select to download pcasa automatically). For me, this is the easiest way. If you need further support, fell free to comment this post and ask.